# Typescript inferred type of array deconstruction conflict

Tags: typescript, type-inference, react-typescript

Hi I'm new to typescript and am unsure about how to coerce the type of an array deconstruction, such that it matches the type of an input to a function (React FC).

In this case that means the deconstructed parameter being a string type only as opposed to string | undefined. (because I want typescript to show an error if the prop is undefined).

[Here is a code sandbox which runs the code and syntax highlights the type error.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-pp7vzs?file=/src/App.tsx)

or

Here is some code that demonstrates the issue:

```
const data = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
]

//react components
interface showItemProps {a: string, b: string, c:string}
function ShowItem({a, b, c}:showItemProps){
    return <div>{`${a} ${b} ${c}`}</div>
}

function ShowAllItems(){
    return <div>
        {data.map(([a,b,c], i) => <ShowItem a={a} b={b} c={c} key={i}/> )}
    </div>
}
```

This is the resulting type error:

```
(property) showItemProps.a: string
Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
tst1.tsx(8, 26): The expected type comes from property 'a' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & showItemProps'
```

I tried explictly adding types in certain places but it doesnt seem to solve the issue, and couldnt find any similar questions, any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Comment: try : `interface showItemProps {a?: string; b?: string; c?:string}`

Comment: yup that works, but was wondering if there was any way to make the props only of type string, ty :D.

Comment: (because i want the component to throw an error if the type of a prop is undefined)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple options:

1. Use the `as const` keyword to have TypeScript infer stricter types:

```
const data = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
] // Has type string[][]

const constData = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
] as const // has type [['a1', 'b1', 'c1'], ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']]
```

That fixes the issue because now the compiler knows that each element of the outer array is an array with three elements, which means that `a`, `b` and `c` will never be undefined. Drawback of this option: It really only works with static data, since the array will be readonly through the `as const` keywords.

2. Nuke the "problematic" config:

The compiler considers values in the array undefined because you specified `"noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true` in your tsconfig.json. That means that every element of an array that isn't typed as a tuple (more on that in a second) is considered potentially undefined. Removing that entry from the tsconfig or setting the value to false, will also disable that behaviour.

3. Help the compiler with explicit tuple types:

Tuple types define the structure of an array: `[string, string, string]` says "This array contains exactly three string elements.", `[string, string, string, ...unknown]` says "This array contains three string elements in the first three positions and then some other stuff after it. In both cases, the rule mentioned under point 2 will understand that there are indeed three string elements in the array and not bother you when you try to use them. You can make use of this in one of two ways:

3.1 Type your data that way:

```
const data: [string, string, string][] = [
    ['a1', 'b1', 'c1'],
    ['a2', 'b2', 'c2'],
];
```

Now all elements are guaranteed to be three strings (and unlike the `as const` keywords, the array remains mutable).

3.2 Explicit typeguard and check

```
<div>
  {data
    .filter((x): x is [string, string, string] => x.length >= 3)
    .map(([a, b, c], i) => (
      <ShowItem a={a} b={b} c={c} key={i} />
    ))
  }
</div>
```

If you don't know how long your data is, you can add a filter with typeguard to the mix. The `filter` function has a return type of `x is [string, string, string]` which means that if the predicate returns true, typescript may assume that the parameter `x` is of the type given in the function. The outcome is the same as in 3.1 but actually checks at runtime that at least 3 elements are present.

Comment: Thank you for such a comprehensive answer, it helped me alot :D.